# SwiftUI: GMSMapView does not conform to protocol UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swiftui, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to add GMS Mapview from the google maps api into my app.
When I followed a tutorial for how to implement it, Xcode cant seem to understand that GMSMapview is an UIView.

This is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMaps

struct MapsView: UIViewRepresentable {

private let zoomLevel: Float = 10.0
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationService()

func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some GMSMapView {
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.lat, longitude: locationManager.lat, zoom: zoomLevel)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    return mapView
}

func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
    mapView.animate(toLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: locationManager.lat, longitude: locationManager.lon))
}

}
```

Xcode does not show any type of solutions for me to make it conform either.

In my Podfile I have only added "GoogleMaps" without version num. So I believe I am using the newest version.

Is this a known bug in the Google Maps package or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `some` word.

```
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> GMSMapView { //<-- here
    let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: locationManager.lat, longitude: locationManager.lat, zoom: zoomLevel)
    let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
    return mapView
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. Im kinda new to the "some" keyword and when it should be used.